# Linking with boost libraries which depend on WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, boost

I used Boost.UUID to generate a random string like this:

```
  boost::uuids::random_generator generator;
  cout << uuids::to_string(generator()) << endl;
```

After triggered build, I got error of `undefined reference to BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvide...`.
Then I had to search for document of undefined functions and link manually with `bcrypt.lib` to pass the build step.

**My Question:** Do I have a better way to link successfully without manually specifying win32 libs like that. Just adding some definition in cmake like `BOOST_AUTOMATIC_LINKING...`

I'm looking for a cross-platform library and decided to use boost. But if it has to link manually on each platform like this seems not quite easy for in-experienced developers if they encounter same issue later.

thanks,

Comment: Not really there is at best a hint buried in the docs here see the section __Preprocessor Macros__ - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/uuid/doc/uuid.html#Random%20Generator

Comment: Boost.UUID does support auto-linking, but it is inherently non-portable. The user will have to deal with manual linking when auto-linking is not supported by the compiler (or disabled via config macros).